# Tableview was not getting refreshed from alertview?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application I have a table view in second view controller. After some time I display an alert view using timer on which I have two buttons **yes and no**. When I click yes the alert view gets dismissed and when I click the no it should delete all items in table view and reload it.

**Problem**

I am not able to refresh the table view when I go to first view controller and return to second view controller.If I am in same view controller, it reloads perfectly.

**Timer function**

```
start_Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(start_method) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**Alert show**

```
 -(void)start_method
    {
           Timerfunction_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You have less than one minute before all items on your order list are released as it is about to exceed the 15-minutes hold time allocated to you to complete your order. Do you wish to continue ordering this item?" 
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
     [Timerfunction_alert show];
    }



 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
      if (alertView == Timerfunction_alert)
       {
         if (buttonIndex == 0)
          {
            //here to refresh the table view
           [self.tableview reloaddata]
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I assume you omitted the refresh code to spare us the gory details, but it's hard to diagnose why your eventual call to `reloadData` (which I assume must be there if you have it working on the same view controller) on your table view isn't working without seeing more code.

Comment: You haven't called `[tableView reloadData];` anywhere. This method is used to refresh the data within the table view.

Comment: @CodeBandits am use that reload date but not able to refresh the table view.

Comment: @Yugesh: How are you removing the items in the tableView? reloadData does not remove datas from tableview unless you have your datasource changed(ie; array)

Comment: @MeeraJPai yes am delete the NSMutable array values.

Comment: While coming back from first viewcontroller to second viewcontroller i guess you are somewhere populating the array again. Please check it

Comment: @Yugesh where all do you call `[tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: @MeeraJPai when i delete the NSMutable array the array will be empty but not able to call this `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate methode

Comment: @ArunKumar in alert view delegate method

Comment: @Yugesh: Yes when your array is empty your delegate would end up crashing. As you want to show empty table after deleting its contents, empty your array and check there at in the delegate,  tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:section. If its empty return 1.

Comment: @MeeraJPai i will check the delegate tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:section but i t return 0.

Comment: @Yugesh: Yes return zero

Comment: @MeeraJPai but it not refresh the table view.

Comment: @Yugesh what is that `paymentalert`?

Comment: @ArunKumar sorry,am mention wrongly now am edited its Timerfunction_alert.

Comment: @Yugesh [chat] (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31631/room-for-arun-kumar-and-yugesh)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(start_method) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience tells me that you should follow this snippet

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
      if (alertView == paymentalert)
       {
         if (buttonIndex == 0)
          {
// reload table after main thread gets over, sothat app doesn't crash
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ReloadTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

         }
      }
 }

//here to refresh the table view
-(void)ReloadTable
{
           [self.tableview reloaddata]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(start_method) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)start_method
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You have less than one minute before all items on your order list are released as it is about to exceed the 15-minutes hold time allocated to you to complete your order. Do you wish to continue ordering this item?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    alert.tag=1;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag==1)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            //here to refresh the table view
            [self.tableview reloaddata]
        }
    }
}
```